# float calculation in computer

Tags: floating-point, hardware

Could someone please explain, how come below two sequence of operations yields different results in computer machine/hardware/ calculator?

Sequence 1
Step 1: 1/3
Step 2: (result of step 1) * 3
Answer = 1

Sequence 2
Step 1: .3333333333( upto possible entry)
Step 2: (number of step 1) * 3
Answer = .9999999999

As far I know when floating number cannot be stored or represented 100% precisely by computer. If sequence 1 is producing round off value, then why not Sequence 2.
Or is there any harwired algorithm which keeps check of 1/3, 2/3 to be processed specially?

I have tried this in Mobile calculator, Windows calculator app, Microsoft excel sheet. All give same result.

Comment: Because 1/3 is different to 0.3333333333...

Comment: But we know that memory has limited fix size so storing .33333 will result in some truncation. Then how its treating it differently

Comment: How many threes did you type? For example, in one common format you would need about 16 threes to get the same approximation as calculating 1/3.

Comment: yes 16, 3's in sequence 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many calculators use decimal and use a fixed number of digits. For example, if we calculate 1/3 using seven decimal digits, we get .3333333. This has been rounded down to fit in seven digits. When we multiply that by 3, we get .9999999. Since the result is seven digits, it fits in our seven-digit width, and there is no rounding.

Many computer implementations of arithmetic use binary and also use a fixed number of digits. For example, if we calculate 1/3 using seven binary digits, we get .0101011. This has also been rounded to fit in our seven digits, and it rounded up because the fraction we had to round was more than 1/2 at the position where we were rounding. When we multiply this by 3, the exact answer is 1.0000001. This has eight digits, so we round it to seven digits, yielding 1.000000. (In this case, the fraction at the point where we are rounding is exactly 1/2, for which the rule is to round so the next digit is even, so we round down to make 0.)

I used seven digits just for these examples. Commonly, computer floating-point arithmetic uses 53 binary digits for the fraction part (for the `double` type, 24 for `float`). The number of decimal digits that calculators use varies but is usually more than seven.